# Toggle visibility of an element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to toggle the visibility of an element with JavaScript. It's working, but I have to click once first, which of course isn't optimal. Can someone point out to me why this isn't working properly?

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if(e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#foo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```

Comment: #foo { display: none; }

Comment: So you want #foo to be invisible when you load the page?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Rick Hitchcock pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reverse your `if` and `else` tests.  JavaScript can't read CSS properties from  `style` unless it explicitly sets them:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if(e.style.display == 'none')
    e.style.display = 'block';
  else
    e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#foo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```